# Cloudinary upload error :"could not decode base64 " only with larger file size

Tags: node.js, express, cloudinary

whenever i upload larger image files i get error "couldnot decode base 64" but image uploads when i upload smaller files on cloudinary

```
const mycloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(productImageUpload, {
folder: "products",
width: 400,
height: 450,
quality: 100,
crop: "scale",
```

});

// in app.js

```
app.use(express.json({limit:'50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit:'50mb',extended:true}));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to upload any file that's larger than 100MB, you need to [upload them in chunks](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#chunked_asset_upload). If you wish to implement your own chunk upload, please check the following article. Alternatively, you could also use the `upload_large` feature of the Cloudinary SDK as shown here: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009586100/comments/360002140099

```
const mycloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload_large(productImageUpload, {
  folder: "products",
  width: 400,
  height: 450,
  quality: 100,
  crop: "scale",
});
```

Comment: i am uploading images of only few mb ,images sizes of few kb are uploading with no error, i am using this code in frontend    const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = () => {
        if (reader.readyState === 2) {
          setImagePreview(reader.result);
         
        }
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0],);